# C++/CLI Button change fontstyle of selectedtext at textbox

Tags: c++-cli, visual-studio-2019

Goal: Make a button that will change *FontStyle* of *SelectedText*.
What I have now: form with button and textbox;

```
private: System::Void Button2_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) 
{
    if (textBox1->SelectionLength > 0)
    {
        textBox1->SelectedText->FontStyle = 
    }
}
```

I tried to search this at Microsoft site but c# code only in the example.
How to make it correctly?

Comment: This is not C++ (`c++` tag) code, it is C++/CLI (`c++-cli` tag).  C++/CLI is a different programming language that unfortunately has "C++" mixed in.  (Kind of like Java and JavaScript conflation.)

Comment: you need to use a FontDialog control, look in your toolbox(Ctrl+Alt+X). Drag it onto your form design. Then call the FontDialog function ShowDialog  in your button click event.